# Attribute Table Default Order in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table

I'm having an issue with QGIS version 3.2 Bonn. For my class, a question asks, "What city corresponds to row number 1713 for the Colleges and Universities shapefile?". I'm having issues answering this, because each time I load the shapefile into QGIS, the attribute table order is randomized, giving me a different city each time.

How can I open the "default" version of the attribute table for this layer, so that the order of rows is not randomized each time?

Comment: On a side note, it would be much safer to look for a specific ID rather than a row number. It is best to avoid relying on an uncontrolled displayed order (for example, if you look for building 123, it should not matter if someone has inserted/deleted building 111)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known bug in QGIS 3.2. https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19299

For answering the class question, I recommend you find out what version of QGIS your teacher expects you to use, then test in that version. Or just download QGIS 2.18, which is the latest long-term release and should be relatively bug-free.