# Sort SHP features by feature ID in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, features, sorting, dbf

I have a shapefile which does not have any ID column. I put them in a validator, which indicates the ID of faulty features, based on the DBF line order. But by opening the shapefile attribute table in QGIS (tried 3.4 and 3.22), I cannot know the ID of each feature, since QGIS apply a "default" sort which does not match the original file order (it seems to be due to [an old bug](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19299)).

The only way I found is to hover each feature one by one, and check the feature ID in the tooltip ... it can be VERY, VERY long.

An example can be seen in [this related answer of another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/328487/112815):
[image: Example]

Is there any other way to do see DBF line number in QGIS? And to sort attribute table using it? Is the bug causing this still active?

Comment: Have you tried adding another ID column using `@rownumber`?

Comment: Or using `$id`?

Comment: secondary question: delete this here and post it as a separate question.

Comment: since the ticket is not marked as resolved I would assume it is there - if it's really bothering you then you'll need to get it fixed either by writing some code or paying someone to do it.

Comment: Be careful! -- Record ID is the only thing that ties the `.shp`/`.shx` pair to `.dbf`. If you sort the dBase without the geometries, you might never get them to link back up again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To only sort the attribute table, open it and do right click somewhere on the fieldnames:

[image]

Choose sort and enter the expression `$id`:

[image]

---

To create a new layer, with features ordered by the (previous) feature id, you can run "Order by Expression" from processing toolbox and use the expression `$id`:

[image]